# Can't use RTSP VLC with python on debian

Tags: linux, debian, python, vlc

So I can't use RTSP with VLC, I saw the problem with debian policy but I don't know how to figure it out

(sorry for bad english)

There is my error:

```js
[00007f18a000a8c0] satip stream error: Failed to play RTSP session
[00007f18a000a8c0] satip stream error: Failed to teardown RTSP session
[00000000034123f0] main input error: Your input can't be opened
[00000000034123f0] main input error: VLC is unable to open the MRL 'rtsp://192.168.1.115:8554/stream'. Check the log for details.
```

I tried to install VLC with snapd but it doesn't work because I have this error:

```py
 NameError: no function 'libvlc_new'
```